# Angular Directive: Custom attribute not properly resolving

Tags: angular, angular-directive, ng-bootstrap

I'm using ng-bootstrap to display an error tooltip for a bunch of input fields inside a form.
Since most of the code is repeated, I thought about creating a directive to set the attributes to the elements based on some few parameters:

From this:

```html
<div class="value" tooltipClass="tooltip-error"
     [ngbTooltip]="'getError(form, 'serial')'"
     [openDelay]="300" [closeDelay]="500"
     [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && form.get('serial').errors }">
  <input formControlName="serial" type="text" placeholder="Serial Number" />
</div>
```

To this:

```html
<div class="value" [form]="form" [submitted]="submitted" [controlName]="'serial'">
  <input formControlName="serial" type="text" placeholder="Serial Number" />
</div>
```

Using this directive:

```js
import { Directive, Input, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

import { formError } from '@core/helpers';

@Directive({
  selector: '[submitted][form][controlName],[submitted][form][controlName][disabled]',
  host: {
    'tooltipClass': 'tooltip-error',
    '[attr.openDelay]': '300',
    '[attr.closeDelay]': '500',
    '[class.is-invalid]': 'submitted && form.get(controlName).errors',
    '[class.not-allowed-cursor]': 'disabled',
    '[class.no-text-selection]': 'disabled',
  }
})
export class FormControlDirective {
  _controlName: string = '';
  _form!: FormGroup;
  _submitted!: boolean;

  @Input()
  public get submitted(): boolean {
    return this._submitted;
  }
  public set submitted(v : boolean) {
    this._submitted = v;
    this.resolveTooltip();
  }

  @Input()
  public get form(): FormGroup {
    return this._form;
  }
  public set form(v : FormGroup) {
    this._form = v;
    this.resolveTooltip();
  }

  @Input()
  public get controlName(): string {
    return this._controlName;
  }
  public set controlName(v : string) {
    this._controlName = v;
    this.resolveTooltip();
  }

  @Input() disabled: boolean = false;

  @HostBinding('[attr.ngbTooltip]')
  ngbTooltip: string = '';

  resolveTooltip() {
    //This method gets an error message based on the type of error.
    //I tried to put the value between ' ', with no avail.
    this.ngbTooltip = formError(this.submitted, this.form, this.controlName);
  }
}
```

First, I noticed that the value in the HostBinding does not update automatically, the same way as the `host` attributes, so I created getters/setter.

But still, the tooltip does not appear. If I add the attributes manually, the tooltip appears normally.

Here's the rendered result of the manual way:

```html
<div tooltipclass="tooltip-error" class="value is-invalid" ng-reflect-tooltip-class="tooltip-error" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="Error example" ng-reflect-open-delay="300" ng-reflect-close-delay="500" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
  <input formcontrolname="serial" type="text" placeholder="Serial Number" ng-reflect-name="serial" class="ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-touched">
</div>
```

And here's the rendered result of using a directive:

```html
<div tooltipclass="tooltip-error" class="value is-invalid" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]" ng-reflect-submitted="true" ng-reflect-control-name="serial" opendelay="300" closedelay="500" ngbtooltip="'Serial number is required'">
  <input formcontrolname="serial" type="text" placeholder="Serial Number" ng-reflect-name="serial" class="ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-touched">
</div>
```

From what I could understand, it looks like the attributes are not being "parsed", not appearing as `ng-reflect-`.

Trying to simply add the name of the attributes as starting with `ng-reflect-` didn't work. :)

What's going on and how to fix it?

---

### Edit:

I think that I understand what's happening.
I'm trying to trigger the selector of another directive (`[ngbTooltip]`, from `ng-boostrap`) within my custom directive.

If I create something simpler, like this:

```js
'[attr.ngbTooltip]': 'tooltipText',
//...

tooltipText: string = '';
//...

resolveTooltip() {
  this.tooltipText = formError(this.submitted, this.form, this.controlName);
}
```

I'll get an attribute named as `ngbTooltip=""` instead of `[ngbTooltip]=""` which is the trigger for the `ngbTooltip` from `ng-bootstrap`.

Is there any way to trigger a selector of another directive from a custom directive?

---

### The answer?

This looks **really wrong**, but it works.
I can't think anymore today.

What I did was to extend from `ngbTooltip` and set the values to the internal properties that are used by the tooltip.

```js
import { Directive, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

import { formError } from '@core/helpers';
import { NgbTooltip } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Directive({
  selector: '[submitted]',
  host: {
    '[class.is-invalid]': 'submitted && form.get(controlName).errors',
    '[class.not-allowed-cursor]': 'disabled',
    '[class.no-text-selection]': 'disabled'
  }
})
export class FormControlDirective extends NgbTooltip implements OnInit {
  _controlName: string = '';
  _form!: FormGroup;
  _submitted: boolean = false;

  @Input()
  public get submitted(): boolean {
    return this._submitted;
  }
  public set submitted(v : boolean) {
    this._submitted = v;
    this.resolveTooltip();
  }

  @Input()
  public get form(): FormGroup {
    return this._form;
  }
  public set form(v : FormGroup) {
    this._form = v;
    this.resolveTooltip();
  }

  @Input()
  public get controlName(): string {
    return this._controlName;
  }
  public set controlName(v : string) {
    this._controlName = v;
    this.resolveTooltip();
  }

  @Input() disabled: boolean = false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.tooltipClass = 'tooltip-error';
    this.openDelay = 300;
    this.closeDelay = 500;

    super.ngOnInit();
  }

  resolveTooltip() {
    this.ngbTooltip = formError(this.submitted, this.form, this.controlName);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim Deschryver adressed a similar use case here with PrimeNg directive :

https://dev.to/this-is-angular/use-angular-directives-to-extend-components-that-you-dont-own-1jio

In my opinion, just applying an attribute of a directive through a custom directive is not a nice way, due to the strong link you would create, but I don't say that this could not work at all.

Tim solution looks nice, but you need to map the ng-bootstrap existing directive, instead of the ones you mapped.

Your solution to extend the class looks quite "edge" like you say ;)
Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

`selector` is how you apply the directive - a simple keyword should be enough.

In your case you're mostly interested in host class properties which is understandable and that part looks about right.

You could start by fixing the selector section and try to re-apply your directive.

Here is an example of a tooltip directive: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tooltip-directive-editable-egzs44?file=app%2Ftooltip.directive.ts

Comment: Thanks for the sample. Looks like my issue is goes a bit deeper. I'm trying to trigger a directive's selector from another directive. Maybe that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `HostBinding` syntax may be incorrect

```js
@HostBinding('[attr.ngbTooltip]')
  ngbTooltip: string = '';
```

should be:

```js
@HostBinding('attr.ngbTooltip')
  ngbTooltip: string = '';
```

Also, the **directive selector** name can only be used for a single `@Input` as far as I know, but you're using it for multiple inputs e.g `[submitted]="submitted" [controlName]="'serial'"` - I don't think this will work

Comment: I tried both changes, but it didn't work. I think that understand what's happening now. It looks like I can't trigger another directive selector from another directive.